# How to keep aspect ratio after changing window size?

Tags: libgdx, resize, window, size, resolution

So i have very little knowledge of how ortho cameras and such work, and it's catching up to me, as my game is breaking if you change the size of the window. The normal 800x600 window when you open it looks like this:

[Normal Resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iLyX.png)

and broken...

[Increased res (changing the screen size before it starts)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NooQF.png)

I want to always keep the same aspect ratio, and just stretch what's on screen whenever the size is changed. This is because increasing the resolution and screen size allows the player to see more of the map which makes my game too easy. So how do I make it so changing the screen to any size just always simply stretches the image? or even not stretch at all, and just add black borders to fill the extra space? (note: this is a desktop game, not android....right now) Here is the first few lines from my render method. I don't have anything put in my resize method yet.

```
        public void render(float delta) {


            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            renderer.setView(camera);
            renderer.render();
            batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);     

            camera.update();

            batch.begin();
```

Answer (score 0):

[FitViewport](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports#fitviewport) can be used to make screen stay in desired aspect ratio. 
But if you want your game to get stretched instead of black borders then OrthographicCamera is enough. It's hard to tell where you are messing structure with this tiny piece of code.

Comment: can you explain how orthographic camera can do that? because if you increase the size of the screen while the game is running then i get the desired effect, but if i do it before the level is loaded, then the aspect ratio gets messed with. Also what other part of my code do you need? This is all that's in render that deals with the camera, renderer etc. and like i said my resize is empty right now.